# Error while accessing secured EJB (@RolesAllowed) deployed on Glassfish 4 payara server

Tags: ejb, glassfish-4, payara, orb, iiop

I am getting below error while accessing secured EJB (`@RolesAllowed`) deployed on GlassFish-A ,
I am accessing this EJB from Application deployed on Glassfish-B.

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot propagate
>   username/password required by target when using run as identity    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecurityContextUtil.getSecurityContext(SecurityContextUtil.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecClientRequestInterceptor.send_request(SecClientRequestInterceptor.java:271)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.InterceptorInvoker.invokeClientInterceptorStartingPoint(InterceptorInvoker.java:290)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.PIHandlerImpl.invokeClientPIStartingPoint(PIHandlerImpl.java:378)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:323)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.request(ClientDelegateImpl.java:220)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:192)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:150)
>     at
>   com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.codegen._GenericEJBHome_Generated_DynamicStub.create(com/sun/ejb/codegen/_GenericEJBHome_Generated_DynamicStub.java)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor131.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.lookupRemote30BusinessObject(EJBUtils.java:428)
>     ... 107 more

Comment: I'd have to look into it, but seems a limitation. Easiest workaround is probably to make sure (if possible) that the remote EJB call is not done from an EJB that's annotated with `@RunAs`.

Comment: @ArjanTijms , the class where lookup is written is not annotated with 'RunAs'

Comment: Could be somewhere down the stack as well, i.e. by the class that calls the class doing the lookup etc. `RunAs` can also be defined in xml instead of via an annotation.

Comment: It  finds  the  privateCredSet.isEmpty() then it considers it as  "runas" case.    Line number 837 in below code. In my case it is getting privatecredSet as empty set.
  https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/32f9e683cf01ed0b96de79648dafefa0a6087aa2/appserver/security/ejb.security/src/main/java/com/sun/enterprise/iiop/security/SecurityMechanismSelector.java